# How can I prove that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2i-1)^{2}} = \frac{π^2}{8}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the series $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^{2}} = \frac{π^{2}}{6}$$

How can I prove that: $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2i-1)^{2}} = \frac{π^2}{8}$$

I have been looking for it all over the web, I am certain it is out there, but I am not too familiar with the mathematical terms in English. Any links or help would be appreciated.

Comment: My answer here may help you a bit, the series is not the same but..it's the same. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1684397/show-that-fractete2t-1-is-integrable/1684438#1684438

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write
$$
\frac{\pi^2}{6} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)^2}  + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2} 
$$
(i.e., separate the sum into even and odd indices). Then observe that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)^2}   = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{\pi^2}{6} .
$$
Can you conclude from there?

Comment: yes, thank you, I was missing the sum part.

Comment: You're welcome... breaking into even and odd is a rather nice nice trick (which has other applications).

Comment: yeah, I am not familiar with series in general (my other questions have been about series and sequences as well), so it's nice to get some tips.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac1{i^2} = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac1{(2i - 1)^2} +  \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac1{(2i)^2}$$