# What is the result of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x(x+1)}\ln(x+1)dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Is there a result for
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x(x+1)}\ln(x+1)dx
$$
If not, is there any upper bound for that?

Update: The result is $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. But how to prove it?

Comment: I'm quite sure the integral is well-defined

Comment: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+from+0+to+infinity+ln%28x%2B1%29%2F%28x%28x%2B1%29%29&x=0&y=0

Comment: Well first you are going to have to substitute the upper bound $\infty$ for a variable say $t$ and then present the integral as a limit.

Comment: I notice that so far you have asked 10 questions on StackExchange and not once have you shown any of your own work on the problem.  What exactly have you tried yourself to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use substitution $u=\frac{x}{x+1}$. Then $x=1-\frac{1}{1-u}$ and
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x(x+1)}\ln(x+1)dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{u}\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-u}\right)du=Li_{2}(1)=\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}
\end{align}
where $Li_{2}(z)$ is [dilogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html).

Answer (score 3):

Let $I$ denote the integral. Substituting $u = \ln(x+1)$, we get:

$$I = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{u}{e^u -1 }du$$

So:

$$I = -\int_0^{\infty} \frac{ue^{-u}}{1- e^{-u}} du = - \int_0^{\infty} ue^{-u} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (e^{-u})^n du = -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} ue^{-(n+1)u}du$$

Integrating by parts,

$$\int_0^{\infty} ue^{-(n+1)u}du = -\frac1{(n+1)^2}$$

Hence, $I = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{(n+1)^2} = \pi^2/6$

Comment: Do you reckon the $-\frac1{n+1}$ should be $\frac1{(n+1)^2}$ because the harmonic series is divergent.

Comment: @ZackNi I do "reckon" and I fixed the typo $5$ minutes ago or something

Answer (score 2):

Let $u = \ln(x+1) \implies x = e^u-1,dx = e^udu, x+1 = e^u $

The integral becomes: $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x(x+1)}\ln(x+1)dx= \begin{equation}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{u}{e^u-1} du
\end{equation}$$

Which is similar to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130167/improper-integral-of-dfracxex-1) which shows that $\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{u}{e^u-1} du
\end{equation} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Answer (score 1):

Let the integral be denoted as $I$. Make the substitution $u={x+1}$ and $du=dx$

we have $$I=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(u)}{(u-1)u}du.$$ Now let $u=\frac{1}{z}$ so that $du=\frac{-1}{z^2}dz.$

Now $I=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(z)}{z-1}dz.$

Now rewrite the integrand as a geometric series as such $$\frac{\ln(z)}{z-1}=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\ln(z)z^n.$$

Replace this with the integrand in $I.$ Now we will integrate term by term.

Use the identity $\int_{0}^{1} \ln(z)z^n dz=-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2},$ which you can derive by integration by parts or differentiation under the integral sign.

Thus, we have $$I=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}.$$

To find the exact value of $I$, which is $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ look at this http://math.cmu.edu/~bwsulliv/MathGradTalkZeta2.pdf

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}\mathrm{d}x &= \int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}\mathrm{d}x + \int_1^\infty\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}\mathrm{d}x + \int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})}{\frac{1}{x}(1+\frac{1}{x})x^2}\mathrm{d}x\tag{1} \\
&= \int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}-\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\mathrm{d}x + \int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)-\ln x}{1+x}\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}\\
&= -\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^1\frac{(-1)^k x^k}{kx}\mathrm{d}x- \sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^1(-1)^k x^k\ln x\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}\\
&= -\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}\int_0^1(-1)^k x^a\mathrm{d}x\bigg{|}_{a=k}\tag{4}\\
&= -\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}\frac{(-1)^k}{a+1}\bigg{|}_{a=k}\\
&= -\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^2}\\
&= -\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}\tag{5} \\ &= 2\cdot\frac{\pi^2}{12}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\tag{6} \end{align}$$

**Explanations :**

$(1)$ Substitute $x\rightarrow 1/x$

$(2)$ Use $1/(x(1+x))=1/x-1/(1+x)$

$(3)$ Expand $ln(1+x)$ and $1/(1+x)$ in Taylor series

$(4)$ Use $x^k\ln x = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}x^a\bigg{|}_{a=k}$

$(5)$ Shift $k+1\rightarrow 1$

$(6)$ use $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k/k^2 = -\pi^2/12$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x + 1} \over x\pars{x + 1}}\,\dd x} &\
\stackrel{\pars{x + 1}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\
\int_{1}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over \pars{x - 1}x}\,\dd x\
\stackrel{x\ \mapsto\ 1/x}{=}\,\,\,\,
-\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] &\ \stackrel{x\ \mapsto\ \pars{1 - x}}{=}\,\,\,\,\,
\underbrace{-\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x}
_{\ds{\color{#f00}{\large ?}}}\ =\
\int_{0}^{1}\Li{2}'\pars{x}\,\dd x = \Li{2}\pars{1} =
\color{#f00}{\pi^{2} \over 6}
\end{align}

> Otherwise,
>   $$
> \color{#f00}{\large ?} =
> -\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x =
> \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n}\int_{0}^{1}x^{n - 1}\,\dd x =
> \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}} = \color{#f00}{\pi^{2} \over 6}
> $$

Comment: Very efficient!  +1